# Как использовать php-переменные в css-файлах?

Tags: php, css

У меня есть файл style.css и php-страничка. Есть ли какой-то способ, чтобы использовать переменные, которые находятся в php-странице,например, $color = $000;, в css-файле. Например, в style.css:

```css
body {

color: <?= $color ?>;

}
```

Comment: только если создать php файл и написать <style></style>

Comment: Можно через js получить данные из php и изменить стиль определённого поля используя параметр php.

Comment: @user363198, А лучше всего так не делать!

Answer (score 2):

### Для контроля стилей из кода/админки сайта

Если вы хотите корректировать из кода скрипта/админки сайта стили элементов, то нужно записывать переменные не в файл CSS, а добавить на странице куда планируете выводить переменные  блок и в него всё записывать:

```
<style>
body {
    color: <?= $color ?>;
}
</style>
```

В вашем примере - (php страница и css файл к ней), то, что вы запишите в `<style></style>` страницы будет приоритетнее стилей из файла css. Потому вам не нужно переносить все содержимое style.css. Запишите только нужные строки.

Ещё вариант - генерировать через php css файлы с нужными переменными и сохранять на сервер в виде style.css. Костыльный метод, не рекомендую.

### Для удобной разработки

Если же ваша цель - удобно разрабатывать ресурс, и переменные требуются для того, чтобы упростить процесс - используйте SCSS/SASS. Это позволит поместить, например цвет в переменную и дальше использовать переменную в стилях элементов. Что в дальнейшем позволит автоматически изменять цвет в одном месте, а не во всех строчках где он используется.

Примеры: https://smartideal.net/kak-podklyuchit-scss/

Нюансы: http://tpverstak.ru/sass-scss/

SCSS/SASS поддерживается всеми современными IDE.

Документация к phpStorm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если считаете ответ полезным - выберите как решение и поднимите вверх. (Я тут ради репутации). Успехов!